# New Install Running Slow

Tags: drivers, nvidia

Environment:

I recently installed Kali Linux 2016.2 and successfully installed the appropriate drivers for a Nvidia GTX 970. I am running an intel(R) Core(TM) i7-5820K CPU @ 3.30GHz, X99 Gigabyte motherboard and 32 Gb of RAM.

The Problem:

I am noticing that the system is lagging while doing simple tasks like browsing the Internet. I have updated and upgraded the system and rebooted already. Running `top` shows very little hardware utilization. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: try disabling 'intel speed-step' from bios. this is notorious for performance regression in linux os.

Comment: Thanks. I disabled it by that doesn't appear to have fixed the issue.

Comment: It would be good to investigate further towards finding the actual reasons for your performance issues. It is actually unlikely that intel speed-step is the root issue, and running with it disabled will cost you considerable power.

Comment: I agree and that is why I posted the question. I'm looking for help in troubleshooting the issue. I feel like it could be a driver optimization problem but I'm not a linux "expert" so I don't exactly know where to go from there.

Comment: how do I make sure that I have the latest intel CPU driver?

Comment: You are likely using the intel_pstate CPU frequency scaling driver. Check via `cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_driver`. As the first test, you  could try the acpi-cpufreq CPU frequency scaling driver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to resolve my problem. I would like to give Doug Smythies a shout out for pointing me in the right direction!

I indeed was running the intel_pstate CPU frequency driver. the following is what I did to resolved it.

1. Disable intel_psate. You can do this by modifying `/etc/default/grub` and adding `intel_pstate=false` parameter to the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` line. It should look like this:
   `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=”quiet splash intel_pstate=disable"`.
   Then save the file and run `sudo update-grub`.
2. Install cpufrequtils package: `sudo apt-get install cpufrequtils`
3. Edit `/etc/init.d/cpufrequtils` file and set the following line to the governor you need (performance in my case): `GOVERNOR=”performance”`
4. reboot

Comment: I would sure like to understand more about your troubles with the intel_pstate driver using, I assume, the powersave governor. Using the performance governor, you shouldn't notice any difference between the two scaling drivers (as I mentioned on another question). What version of Ubuntu are you running? What kernel version are you running?

Comment: I would assume you are correct regarding the difference between the two drivers. I just didn't bother with switching back to the intel_pstate. I am running the latest Kali Linux 2016.2. Kernel 4.6

Comment: @DougSmythies I have a new laptop running intel_pstate and powersave. I notice the speed always lurks around 800 Mhz instead of turbo-boosting to 3600 Mhz like the old laptop used to do. On the other hand the new laptop is better that the fan doesn't appear to come on. You can set the fan to "performance" mode in BIOS in which case for a minute or so it sounds like a jet engine slowly powering up. Ubuntu 16.04, Kernels 4.4, 4.10, 4.12 and 4.14. I

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix : I made a [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69972/doug-s-and-wineunuuchs2unix) where we can investigate your issue.